# SQL Server 2005 percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

im using sql server 2005.
I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Proyectos2](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Proyecto] [varchar](255) NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clientes2](

[Vendedora] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Proyecto] [varchar](255) NULL  )



 insert into proyectos2
values
(
'Proyecto1'
)
insert into proyectos2
values
(
'Proyecto2'
)
insert into clientes2
values
(
'Jessica','Proyecto1'
)
insert into clientes2
values
(
'Jessica','Proyecto1'
)
insert into clientes2
values
(
'Mariel','Proyecto2'
)
```

then this query:

```
    Declare @Names As Varchar(Max), @strSQL Varchar(Max);
DECLARE @sum AS varchar(MAX);
Select @Names = Stuff((Select ',' + QuoteName(Proyecto)
From Proyectos2 Group By Proyecto Order by Proyecto For XML Path('')), 1, 1, '');
Select @sum = Stuff(
(
Select ', 1.0 * SUM(' + QuoteName(Proyecto) + ') as ' + QuoteName(Proyecto)
From Proyectos2 
Group By Proyecto 
Order by Proyecto For XML Path('')
), 1, 1, '') + ', SUM(Total) as Total';
Set @strSQL = 'select case when grouping(Vendedora) = 1 then ''Grand Total'' else Vendedora end as Vendedora, ' + @sum + N'
from (
Select Vendedora, ' + @Names +  ', (' + REPLACE(@Names, '],[', '] + [') + ') as Total' + 
' From (Select Vendedora, Proyecto From Clientes2) as P 
 Pivot (Count(Proyecto) For Proyecto in (' + @Names + ')) As Pvt
) as S
group by
    Vendedora
    with rollup';
SET @strSQL = 'WITH CTE AS ( ' + @strSQL + ' ) ' +
              'SELECT Vendedora,cast(floor(Proyecto1) as varchar) Proyecto1,cast(floor(Proyecto2) as varchar)Proyecto2,Total FROM CTE UNION ALL ' +
              'SELECT ''Porcentaje'',cast( ' + REPLACE(@Names, '],[', '] / Total as varchar) Proyecto1, cast([') + ' / Total as varchar), ''100''' +
              '  FROM CTE ' +
              ' WHERE Vendedora = ''Grand Total'';';
print @strSQL;
Execute (@strSQL);
GO
```

If you execute this code, this is displayed:

```
Vendedora------Proyecto1--------------Proyecto2-----Total
Jessica-------------2-------------------0--------------2
Mariel--------------0-------------------1--------------1
Grand Total---------2-------------------1--------------3
Percentage----------0.666666666666------0.333333333333---100
```

I would like something like this:

```
Vendedora------Proyecto1--------------Proyecto2-----Total
Jessica-------------2-------------------0--------------0.66
Mariel--------------0-------------------1--------------0.33
Grand Total---------2-------------------1--------------1
Percentage----------0.66--------------0.33------------------100
```

That is, two digits after the decimal for the last row, and also for the total of each row.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You might take a look at [str](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function. For instance, `str(0.6666666, 10, 2)`. If you don't need leading spaces enclose str in ltrim: `ltrim(str(0.6666666, 10, 2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm focusing on your saying that you need the total of each row to be a percentage of the final grand total.

In order to do that you're going to need to know what the grand total is before producing each line.  You really would be best off doing that in a reporting tool, such as SSRS, ActiveReports, or Crystal Reports.

But since you asked:  this is the approach I would take:

ETA:  rewritten to be more specific.  NOTE that this is still an example and needs to be adapted for your situation.

```
WITH CTE AS ( <@strSQL> ),
     CTE2 AS (
       SELECT Vendedora, 
              cast(floor(Proyecto1) as varchar) Proyecto1,
              cast(floor(Proyecto2) as varchar) Proyecto2,
              Total 
       FROM   CTE),
       SELECT   Vendedora,
              Proyecto1,
              Proyecto2,
              Total / ( SELECT SUM(Total) FROM CTE2 ) Percentage
       FROM     CTE2    
       UNION  ALL
       SELECT 'Porcentaje',
               <your two columns>
               '100'
       FROM   CTE
```

But this is very messy indeed:  your best bet if possible is to just return the data and do the totaling and percentage-calculations in a reporting tool.

Comment: If i do it in Sql Reporting Services, will Reporting Services generate the sql code for what i need. ie: I can copy the code from reporting services and paste it into sql server?

Comment: No, it won't, sorry:  you need to know the SQL first.  You'd need to work out the SQL first and then paste it into SSRS.  My suggestion of SSRS was based on the assumption that you intended to display the summarized data, nicely formatted, to somebody, in which case SSRS could do your subtotaling and pivoting for you.  That would mean your query could be much simpler.

Comment: Hi, i have managed to fix the last row:                     Vendedora------Proyecto1--------------Proyecto2-----Total Jessica-------------2-------------------0--------------2 Mariel--------------0-------------------1--------------1 Grand Total---------2-------------------1--------------3 Percentage----------0.66-----------0.33------------------100                                 That part is working fine now. But i cant get the percentage for every row in the total column.

I saw your code, but im just confused

Comment: The fundamental idea is this:  to get the percentage of the total represented by a row, you need to already know the total.  I'll rewrite my example a little.

Comment: OK, the code should be much clearer now. This is still an example, though:  you 'll still have to adapt it to your situation (and to the fact that you're generating dynamic SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your values that you want as percentages (like 0.33) times 100.0, then cast that to int to truncate value to percentage without decimal places.

```
cast(percentage * 100.0 as int) as percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

i did this:

```
Declare @Names As Varchar(Max), @strSQL Varchar(Max), @PercentNames varchar(max) ;
DECLARE @sum AS varchar(MAX);

Select @Names = Stuff((Select ',' + QuoteName(Proyecto)
From Proyectos2 Group By Proyecto Order by Proyecto For XML Path('')), 1, 1, '');

Select @PercentNames = Stuff((Select ',' + 'CAST(' + QuoteName(Proyecto)  + '* 100.0/Total AS DECIMAL(10,2))'
From Proyectos2 Group By Proyecto Order by Proyecto For XML Path('')), 1, 1, '');
Select @sum = Stuff(
(
Select ', 1.0 * SUM(' + QuoteName(Proyecto) + ') as ' + QuoteName(Proyecto)
From Proyectos2 
Group By Proyecto 
Order by Proyecto For XML Path('')
), 1, 1, '') + ', SUM(Total) as Total';

Set @strSQL = 'select case when grouping(Vendedora) = 1 then ''Grand Total'' else Vendedora end as Vendedora, ' + @sum + N'
from (
Select Vendedora, ' + @Names +  ', (' + REPLACE(@Names, '],[', '] + [') + ') as Total' + 
' From (Select Vendedora, Proyecto From Clientes2) as P 
 Pivot (Count(Proyecto) For Proyecto in (' + @Names + ')) As Pvt
) as S
group by
    Vendedora
    with rollup';

SET @strSQL = 'WITH CTE AS ( ' + @strSQL + ' ) 
              SELECT *, CAST(Total * 100.0 / (select Total from cte where Vendedora = ''Grand Total'') as Decimal(10,2)) as [Percent]

              FROM CTE UNION ALL 
              SELECT ''Porcentaje'', ' + @PercentNames + ', ''100'', 100' +
              '  FROM CTE ' +
              ' WHERE Vendedora = ''Grand Total'';';

print @strSQL;
Execute (@strSQL);
GO
```

Is working fine.

But i still have a problem:
I want the numbers after the decimal point removed.
What can i do in this case?

Comment: In your second query change your ''Grand Total'') as Decimal(10,2)) to ''Grand Total'') as Decimal(10,0)) and the numbers after the decimal will drop off

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. But sorry, i didn't expresss myself correctly. I meant not just the percent column, but for every value on the query.

Comment: in this line Select ', 1.0 * SUM(' + QuoteName(Proyecto) + ') as ' + QuoteName(Proyecto) replace 1.0 with 1 and in your other decimal(10,2) change it to Decimal(10,0)

Comment: Make sure that you mark this as the answer to your question. :)